# How to properly set up package?

Tags: python, python-packaging

There are a few packages I am constantly importing and a few functions the I've put together for making pretty plots.  I have them organized like so:

```
\mypackage
    __init__.py
    mypackage.py
```

For some reason I have to import as `from mypackage.mypackage import *` which really bothers me (`from mypackage import *`) is what I'm hoping for.

I've tried adding `from mypackage import mypackage` in the **init**.py file as well as more than a few other variations from different web sources but can't seem to get it to work.

A working example can easily be constructed by using the file structure above with an empty **init**.py and any import in the mypackage.py file such as `import numpy as np`.  If it is working you should be able to do from the directory above \mypackage

```
from mypackage import *
np.arange(10)
```

Or you can grab the library at https://gitlab.com/jb4earth/jblib.git if you want to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Well the issue is exactly the *empty* `__init__.py` file. Instead you should place a `from .mypackage import *` there.

Comment: adding the ```.``` in ```.mypackage``` did the trick.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the `.` in `.mypackage` is the solution here [as suggested in the comments]